# Logic Apps - Actions running before condition executes

Tags: azure-logic-apps

In the screenshot below you can see that actions are running even though the preceding condition failed. How (should) I stop this happening?  Improving the screenshot in this version of the question.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, this error message in "condition" doesn't mean the condition fail. It seems your condition passed successfully. There is an action under the "if ture" which failed, so the "condition" will show this message. So I think you should check the actions under the "if true" and improve it but not the "condition".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is really a false-positive statement as it has actually run correctly. There are several reasons why the orchestration still runs despite the failure.

Try to play around with the "Configure run after" option. You can find this by clicking the three dots on the respective action.

Comment: The problem was that one of the actions depending on the condition failed.